# Looping Through Strings and Formatting It To A Table

Tags: python

I have an assignment to do and I need to get the the number of times two teams score and put them in a table in the format below. I did create an empty array to hold the inputs of the user and then i append it to it. I hope i did this right. I am having trouble writing the code to determine the winner (winner column). I know i need to do an IF/ELSE statement but not sure where to put this code.

Desired Output:

```
           Team 1  Team 2  Winner
Match 1    25      22      Team 1
Match 2    25      41      Team 2
Match 3    30      40      Team 2
Winner is Team 2
```

I have tried putting the if/else statement in each 'For Loop' but does not give me the result im looking for. Is there a better way to code what i have already done?

My Code:

```
team1_scores = []
team2_scores = []
matches = ['Match 1', 'Match 2', 'Match 3', 'Match 4', 'Match 5']

for i in range(5):
    team1_scores_input = int(input("Enter scores for Team 1: "))
    team1_scores.append(team1_scores_input)

for i in range(5):
    team2_scores_input = int(input("Enter scores for Team 2: "))
    team2_scores.append(team2_scores_input)


print("{:>20s} {:>13s} {:>15s}".format("Team 1 ", "Team 2", "Winner"))
print("{} {:6d} {:>14d}".format(matches[0], team1_scores[0], 
team2_scores[0]))
print("{} {:6d} {:>14d}".format(matches[1], team1_scores[1], 
team2_scores[1]))
print("{} {:6d} {:>14d}".format(matches[2], team1_scores[2], 
team2_scores[2]))
print("{} {:6d} {:>14d}".format(matches[3], team1_scores[3], 
team2_scores[3]))
print("{} {:6d} {:>14d}".format(matches[4], team1_scores[4], 
team2_scores[4]))
```

Current OUTPUT

```
Enter scores for Team 1: 20
Enter scores for Team 1: 25
Enter scores for Team 1: 20
Enter scores for Team 1: 26
Enter scores for Team 1: 50
Enter scores for Team 2: 40
Enter scores for Team 2: 60
Enter scores for Team 2: 20
Enter scores for Team 2: 10
Enter scores for Team 2: 20
            Team 1         Team 2          Winner
Match 1     20             40               
Match 2     25             60
Match 3     20             20
Match 4     26             10
Match 5     50             20
```

Comment: Is winner the one with the highest score?

Comment: Hi i have edited my OP for the desired output. I would like the winner of both matches to be displayed on the winner column with an if/else statement.

Comment: Winner is the one with the highest score for each match but notice that at the bottom that "actual" winner is the one with the most matches won.

Comment: You are not allowed to vandalize your post and remove its contents. The content you submit to Stack Overflow is governed by [our license agreement](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). At the time of submission, you granted Stack Overflow a perpetual license to distribute the content, as long as they comply with the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

team1_scores = []
team2_scores = []
winning_res = []
matches = ['Match 1', 'Match 2', 'Match 3', 'Match 4', 'Match 5']

for i in range(5):
    team1_scores_input = int(input("Enter scores for Team 1: "))
    team1_scores.append(team1_scores_input)

for i in range(5):
    team2_scores_input = int(input("Enter scores for Team 2: "))
    team2_scores.append(team2_scores_input)

print("{:>20s} {:>13s} {:>15s}".format("Team 1 ", "Team 2", "Winner"))
for i in range(5):
    win = ""
    max_score =  max(team1_scores[i], team2_scores[i])

    if max_score == team1_scores[i] and max_score == team2_scores[i]:
        win = "Tie"
    elif max_score == team1_scores[i]:
        win = "Team 1"
    elif max_score == team2_scores[i]:
        win = "Team 2"
    print("{} {:6d} {:>14d} {:>22s}".format(matches[i], team1_scores[i], team2_scores[i], win))

overall_winner_dict = Counter(winning_res)

max_value = None
for key in overall_winner_dict:
    if max_value is None or max_value < overall_winner_dict[key]:
        max_value = overall_winner_dict[key]
        max_key = key
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter scores for Team 1: 43
Enter scores for Team 1: 54
Enter scores for Team 1: 65
Enter scores for Team 1: 34
Enter scores for Team 1: 54
Enter scores for Team 2: 65
Enter scores for Team 2: 34
Enter scores for Team 2: 65
Enter scores for Team 2: 23
Enter scores for Team 2: 45
             Team 1         Team 2          Winner
Match 1     43             65                 Team 2
Match 2     54             34                 Team 1
Match 3     65             65                    Tie
Match 4     34             23                 Team 1
Match 5     54             45                 Team 1
Overall Winner: Team 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many more clean and precise ways to do this thing but for now, you can manage with this.

```
team1_scores = []
team2_scores = []
matches = ['Match 1', 'Match 2', 'Match 3', 'Match 4', 'Match 5']

winner=[]

for i in range(5):
    team1_scores_input = int(input("Enter scores for Team 1: "))
    team1_scores.append(team1_scores_input)

for i in range(5):
    team2_scores_input = int(input("Enter scores for Team 2: "))
    team2_scores.append(team2_scores_input)

for i in range(5):
    if team1_scores[i]>team2_scores[i]:
        winner.append("Team 1")
    else:
        winner.append("Team 2")
final_winner = "Team 1" if winner.count("Team 1")>winner.count("Team 2") else "Team 2"


print("{:>20s} {:>13s} {:>15s}".format("Team 1 ", "Team 2", "Winner"))
print("{} {:6d} {:>14d} {:>20s}".format(matches[0], team1_scores[0], 
team2_scores[0],winner[0]))
print("{} {:6d} {:>14d} {:>20s}".format(matches[1], team1_scores[1], 
team2_scores[1],winner[1]))
print("{} {:6d} {:>14d} {:>20s}".format(matches[2], team1_scores[2], 
team2_scores[2],winner[2]))
print("{} {:6d} {:>14d} {:>20s}".format(matches[3], team1_scores[3], 
team2_scores[3],winner[3]))
print("{} {:6d} {:>14d} {:>20s}".format(matches[4], team1_scores[4], 
team2_scores[4],winner[4]))
print("Winner is",final_winner)
```

Comment: try giving the same score for both teams with this.

Comment: I think he can handle those cases on his own.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a simple condition check after populating both lists.  Instead of violating the DRY principle, you could put everything you want to display in a loop. You could create a `winners` list like other answers have mentioned, but with this method, you don't have to (not that this is a more preferred method):

```
# ... after asking user input...

for i in range(len(matches)):
    print("{} {:>6d} {:>14d} {:>19s}".format(matches[i], team1_scores[i], 
      team2_scores[i], \
     "Team1" if team1_scores[i] > team2_scores[i] else ""  \
     "Team2" if team1_scores[i] < team2_scores[i] else "Draw"))
```

Note: the `\` is just for improving readability of python code. A one-liner would be unnecessarily long

Answer (score 0):

Added a commented sample below. I made it configurable so you can add as many matches as you want. Also, I think it is more intuitive to enter stats for each game for both teams at the same time to reduce repetition.

```
WINNER_FLAGS = ['Tie', 'Team 1', 'Team 2'] 
matches = ['Match 1', 'Match 2', 'Match 3'] # configurable, can add more matches

def determine_winner(score1, score2):
    ''' given two scores, output corresponding winner or tie '''

    if score1 == score2:
        return WINNER_FLAGS[0]
    elif score1 > score2:
        return WINNER_FLAGS[1]
    else:
        return WINNER_FLAGS[2]

match_stats = []
win_counter = {flag: 0 for flag in WINNER_FLAGS} # track all winners

for match_name in matches:
    # enter scores for each team

    print '\nDetermine {} stats: \n'.format(match_name)
    team1_score = int(input("Enter score for Team 1: "))
    team2_score = int(input("Enter score for Team 2: "))

    # track the winner
    winner = determine_winner(team1_score, team2_score)
    win_counter[winner] += 1

    # store stats for displaying later
    match_stats.append((match_name, team1_score, team2_score, winner))

# display stats
print("{:>20s} {:>13s} {:>15s}".format("Team 1 ", "Team 2", "Winner"))
for match in match_stats:
    match_name, team1_score, team2_score, winner = match
    print("{} {:6d} {:>14d} {:>20s}".format(match_name, team1_score, team2_score, winner))

# extract the top winner !
max_wins = 0
ultimate_winner = None
for winner, num_wins in win_counter.items():
    if num_wins > max_wins:
        ultimate_winner = winner

print("Ultimate winner is {}".format(ultimate_winner) if ultimate_winner != WINNER_FLAGS[0] else 'Its a tie!!!!')
```

sample run:

```
Determine Match 1 stats: 

Enter score for Team 1: 10
Enter score for Team 2: 10

Determine Match 2 stats: 

Enter score for Team 1: 2
Enter score for Team 2: 39

Determine Match 3 stats: 

Enter score for Team 1: 1
Enter score for Team 2: 90
             Team 1         Team 2          Winner
Match 1     10             10                  Tie
Match 2      2             39               Team 2
Match 3      1             90               Team 2
Ultimate winner is Team 2
```